# Android: Is there a way to do Activity Transitions if one of the shared elements is in a Fragment? Activity A Fragment to Activity B

Tags: android, android-layout, android-transitions, activity-transition

I understand that there are Activity Transitions to make transitions for shared elements between Activity A and Activity B like so:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
    Pair.create(view1, "agreedName1"),
    Pair.create(view2, "agreedName2"));
```

There are also Fragment Transitions for Fragments that are in the same Activity. But is there a way to transition shared elements between Activity A's Fragment views and Activity B?

My Activity A has a ViewPager with Fragments that have views that I would like to transition into Activity B's views. So the Views that I want to transition into Activity B are actually in Activity A's Fragment layout, not directly in Activity A's layout.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, fragments don't cause problems with Activity Transitions on their own. The main issue is that fragments tend to load their contents at a later time and the transition system gets confused about what is available.

When there is a transition, the Views don't actually move from one activity to another. There is a snapshot taken of the location and size (and a bitmap) and that information is transferred to Activity B. The corresponding View in Activity B then is transitioned from that location and size to the final location and size. The bitmap is normally not used, but is there in case you need it for a cross-fade or similar.

If the shared element is in a fragment in Activity A, then the outgoing transition is fine -- the View exists and is positioned properly. The only potential problem is the returning transition. When Activity B closes, it is possible for Activity A to need to be restarted (memory pressure, orientation change, etc). In that case, the fragment will have to be recreated and the View placed properly. In `onActivityReenter`, call `postponeEnterTransition` and then when the fragment is loaded and layout has completed, call `startPostponedEnterTransition`. Then Activity B will know what the final position and size of the shared element will be, so it can start its animation.

The same is true in reverse, when Activity B has a shared element in a fragment. You'll have to postpone the enter transition in onCreate until after the fragment is loaded and layout is complete in Activity B.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation about the complications of the lifecycle, George. Do you happen to know what the proper callback for a Fragment is when the Fragment is finished loading? I believe that Fragment's have some kind of onAttach method similar to a View's onAttachToWindow, so my current plan is to wait for that callback in the postponeEnterTransition like you said.

Comment: The fragment's View should be loaded after you receive the `onCreateView`, but the transition shouldn't start then. You'll need to wait until the layout has completed to start the transition, which means that you should add an `OnPreDrawListener` in the `onCreateView`. Remember to remove the `OnPreDrawListener` after it has notified because they aren't one-shot listeners.

Comment: Hey George, are you talking about adding an onPreDrawListener on the onCreateView in the Fragment or the onCreateView of the Activity (which from what I understand is not part of the Activity's lifecycle)? Because the startPostponedEnterTransition is an Activity method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but I did something like this.

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                                (View) viewHolder.clickme, "zoom");
                getActivity().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,
                        R.anim.fadeout);
```

I hope it will help you somehow.